# Create List in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a `List` in a `select new` in `Linq` to set the property of an object.  The linq query is below the object definitions.

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public List<LatLng> coordinates{get;set;}
}

public class LatLng
{
    public double Lat;
    public double Lon;

    public LatLng(double lat, double lon)
    {
      this.Lat = lat;
      this.Lon = lon;
    }
}


List<LatLng> coordinates = null;
var query = from loc in locList
            select new SomeObject
             (
                coordinates = new LatLng(loc.Lat,loc.Lon)
                // I tried the line below but it doesn't work.
                //coordinates =  new LatLng(loc.Lat,loc.Lon).ToList()                    
             );
```

The important line is this

```
coordinates = new LatLng(loc.Lat,loc.Lon)
```

How can I make that into a `List<LatLng>` for the `coordinates` property which is a `List<LatLng>` type?

Comment: You can use reflection to get a list of properties, and then put the relevant ones into a list.  Or if you can, just hard code the list definition.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Thanks, I updated to show the class with constructor

Comment: List<LatLng> coordinates = locList.Select(loc => new LatLng(loc.Lat, loc.Lon).ToList()?

Comment: Is `query` supposed to be a `List<T>` or a `SomeObject()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var query = from loc in locList select 
  new SomeObject { 
    coordinates = new List<LatLng> { 
      new LatLng(loc.Lat,loc.Lon) 
    }
  }
```

Comment: I need to create List of SomeObjects, each with one coordinate from locList.

Comment: OK, then you just forgot the `new List<LatLng>`

Comment: Thanks.  I did that before but didn't use brackets,                             coordinates = new List<LatLng>(new LatLng(loc.Lat,loc.Lon))